# Why I can't see the users that I have created

Tags: user-accounts, active-directory, windows-server-2012, sql-server

I have created 4 users on Active Directory Users and Computer:

But I can't see the users on my computer management under "local users and groups" nor on my sql server!

So, why I does not have "local users and groups" on "computer management"?

[http://imgur.com/5NsqgWB&F467FRZ&OGKV5yn#0](https://imgur.com/5NsqgWB&F467FRZ&OGKV5yn#0)

[image: Screenshot]

[http://imgur.com/5NsqgWB&F467FRZ&OGKV5yn#1](https://imgur.com/5NsqgWB&F467FRZ&OGKV5yn#1)

[image: Screenshot]

[http://imgur.com/5NsqgWB&F467FRZ&OGKV5yn#2](https://imgur.com/5NsqgWB&F467FRZ&OGKV5yn#2)

[image: Screenshot]

**More Details:**For my Sharepoint server installation on Windows server 2012 I have installed AD and created under AD Users and Computers a new organisational Unit. There I have created four users (which you can see in the first screenshot), all have the same account options: "User cannot change the password" and "Password never expires". The Domain of the Server is "dominaserver". Here are the Properties of the users: imgur.com/EQsBpKa

After that I went to Computer Management where I wanted to see if the users was added. First what me have wondered that ther are no "Local user and groups" as usual. WHY?

Then I ignored that and wanted to see if the sql server has added the new users. And in the folder "Logins" (red marked) also no users as expected?

**So my question is: Why on sql-server and computer-management arn't no users allthought I have create them in AD Users and computers**

Comment: What do you mean you can't see them in your local users and groups?  If the are AD accounts then they are NOT local users/groups.  You wouldn't see them there.    AD accounts are not local accounts.

Comment: there was other two screenshots if you give me the link (I dont have it anymore) I could explain you

Comment: I changed the screenshots to links.

Comment: @Zoredache Update

Comment: Your update doesn't really change anything.  The answer is still 'because it is a DC'.

Answer (score 0):

> But I can't see the users on my computer management under "local users and groups"

You appear to be looking at that from your Domain controller.  Domain Controllers do not have local accounts.  They are Domain controllers.

As for SQL Server I am not familiar what what it should look like normally, but I do know Microsoft strongly discourages running SQL server on a Domain Controller.  I would not be surprised at all if you lose some functionality related to account management.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, when you create a user in Active Directory Users and Computers, they are domain accounts not local accounts. They won't show up in Local Users and Groups. If the computer or server is domain-joined you can still use those domain accounts to login to the server or computer however.

If you want to utilize a domain account for SQL login, you have to add that account to SQL Logins.

**How to add domain account to SQL**

1. Make sure your SQL Server is domain-joined
2. Open SQL Server Management Studio
3. Under *Security* > *Logins*, right-click and choose *New Login...*

[image]

4. Select *Windows Authentication* and click the *Search* button

[image]

5. Ensure the *From this location* is set to "Entire Directory" then
       type the domain login you wish to add

[image]

The domain account should now appear under *Security* > *Logins*